# Limit of the solution of $u_t + (x^2 - 1)u_x = 0$

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations

I was trying to find the limit when $t \to +/-\infty$ of the solution of the pde $u_t + (x^2 - 1)u_x = 0$ with initial condition $u(0,x) = f(x)$ where $f$ is continuous and $f \to 0$ when $|x| \to \infty$.

So I found the characteristic $\xi = \frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right| - t$, which gave me the solution

$u(t,x) = f \left( \frac{x+1+(x-1)e^{-2t}}{x+1-(x-1)e^{-2t}} \right)$

So I concluded that $u(t,x) \to f(1)$ as $t \to \infty$ and $x \neq -1$, and $u(t,x) \to f(-1)$ as $t \to \infty$ and $x = -1$. But the solution book states:

$u(t,x) \to f(1)$ as $t \to \infty$ and $x > -1$

$u(t,x) \to f(-1)$ as $t \to \infty$ and $x = -1$

$u(t,x) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ and $x < -1$

Where is my mistake? What do I do for $t \to -\infty$?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote : I found the characteristic $\xi = \frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right| - t \tag 1$, which gave me the solution $u(t,x) = f \left( \frac{x+1+(x-1)e^{-2t}}{x+1-(x-1)e^{-2t}} \right) \tag 2$

Without the intermediate steps between $(1)$ and $(2)$ it isn't possible to point out where exactly the mistake is. Probably, the treatment of the absolute value isn't correct.

I agree with the equation of the characteristic curves :
$$\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right| - t=c$$

So, a form of general solution is :
$$u(x,t)=\Phi\left( \frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right| - t\right)$$
where $\Phi(X)$ is any differentiable function.

An equivalent form, with the related function $F$ :
$$\Phi(X)=F\Big(\exp(2X)\Big)$$
$X=\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right| - t \quad\to\quad \exp(2X)=\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right|e^{-2t}$
$$u(x,t)=F\left(\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right|e^{-2t} \right) \tag 3$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function.

Condition : $u(0,x)=f(x)=F\left(\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right| \right)$

Let $\quad \left|\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right|=\chi \quad 
\begin{cases}
\text{if } |x|>1 \quad\to\quad \chi=\frac{x-1}{x+1} \quad\to\quad x=\frac{1+\chi}{1-\chi} \quad\to\quad F(\chi)=f\left(\frac{1+\chi}{1-\chi}\right)\\
\text{if } |x|<1 \quad\to\quad \chi=-\frac{x-1}{x+1} \quad\to\quad x=\frac{1-\chi}{1+\chi} \quad\to\quad F(\chi)=f\left(\frac{1-\chi}{1+\chi}\right)\\
\end{cases}$

Now, the function $F(\chi)$ is determined. You just have to put it into $(3)$ 
with $\chi=\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right| e^{-2t} $ and simplify in both cases.

IN ADDITION, after further calculus I also got to :

$$u(t,x) = f \left( \frac{x+1+(x-1)e^{-2t}}{x+1-(x-1)e^{-2t}} \right)\quad\text{if}\quad x+1-(x-1)e^{-2t} \neq 0 \tag 4$$

- Case $x>-1\quad;\quad$  $t$ starting from $0$ and $t\to\infty$

$x+1>(x-1)e^{-2t} \quad\implies\quad $ The condition $(4)$ is always fulfilled any $t\geq 0$.

Thus, the above solution $(4)$ is valid and $e^{-2t}\to 0 \quad\implies\quad u(t,x)\to f(1)$

- Case $x=-1$

Again, the condition $4$ is fulfilled. The above solution simplifies to $\quad u(t,-1)= f(-1)\quad $ any $t$.

- Case $x<-1\quad;\quad$  $t$ starting from $0$ and $t\to\infty$

The condition $(4)$ is not fulfilled any $t$.

For a given $x<-1$, the function $\quad y(t)=x+1-(x-1)e^{-2t}\quad$ starts from $y(0)=2$ and decreases to $(x+1)<0$. Hence, $y=0$ for a value $t_m$.

When $t\to t_m$ the argument of the function $f$ in equation $(4)$ tends to infinity. In the wording of the problem, it is specified that $f(\infty)=0$.

Hence $\quad u(t_m,x)=0$.

Beyond this point $t>t_m\;,\quad$ the PDE $\quad u_t+(x^2-1)u_x=0\quad$ is satisfied by the trivial solution $\quad u(t,x)=0$, with initial condition $u(t_m,x)=0$.

Thus, in this case, $u(t,x)=0$ for $t\to\infty$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I indeed forgot to treat the absolute value. But I still get $u(t,x) = f \left( \frac{x+1-(x-1)e^{-2t}}{x+1+(x-1)e^{-2t}} \right)$ when $|x| > 1$ (and $u(t,x) = f \left( \frac{x+1+(x-1)e^{-2t}}{x+1-(x-1)e^{-2t}} \right)$ when $|x| < 1$), which still gives me $u(t,x) \to f(1)$ when $x < -1$

Comment: In fact, your analytical solution is correct. But the further reasoning  leading to $u(t,x)\to f(1)$ is biased. See the addition to my first answer.